# Can I avoid duplicate strings with the sed "a\" command?

Tags: sed

Can I avoid duplicate strings with the sed "a" command?

I added the word "apple" under "true" in my file.txt.

The problem is that every time I run the command "apple" is appended.

```
$ sed -i '/true/a\apple' file.txt  ...execute 3 time
```

```
$ cat file.txt
true
apple
apple
apple
```

If the word "apple" already exists, repeating the sed command does not want to add any more.

I have no idea, please help me

...

I want to do this,

```
...execute sed  command anytime

$ cat file.txt
true
apple
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do add more clear samples of input and expected output in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't want to append the line `apple` if the line following the `true` already contains `apple`. Then this `sed` command should do the trick.

```
sed -i.backup '
/true/!b
$!{N;/\napple$/!s/\n/&apple&/;p;d;}
a\
apple
' file.txt
```

**Explanation of `sed` commands:**

- If the line doesn't contain *true* then jump to the end of the script, which will print out the line read (`/true/!b`).

Otherwise the line contains *true*:

- If it isn't the last line (`$!`) then
  • read the next line (`N`).
  • If the next line doesn't consist of *apple* (`/\napple$/!`) then insert the *apple* between two lines (`s/\n/&apple&/`).
  • Print out the pattern space (`p`) and start a new cycle (`d`)

Otherwise it is the last line (and contains *true*)

- Append *apple* (`a\ apple`)

---

### **Edit:**

The above `sed` script won't work properly if two consecutive *true* line occurs in the file, as pointed out by @potong. The version below should fix this, if I haven't overlooked something.

```
sed -i.backup ':a
               /true/!b
               a\
apple
               n
               /^apple$/d
               ba
' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `/true/!b`: If the line doesn't contain *true*, no further processing is required. Jump to the end of the script. This will print the current pattern space.
- `a\ apple`: Otherwise, the line contains `true`. Append *apple*.
- `n`: Print the current pattern space and appended line (*apple*) and replace the pattern space with the next line. This will end the script if no next line available.
- `/^apple$/d`: If the line read consists of string *apple* then delete it and start a new cycle (because it is already appended before)
- `ba`: Jump to the start of the script (label `a`) without reading an input line.

Comment: What if the line following `true` is `true` (and is not the last line)?

Comment: @potong Thanks for pointing out the flaw. I'm going to amend the answer when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general solution for `sed` unless the file is sorted. If sorted, the following deletes the duplicate lines:

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

This was taken from this link: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/146404-command-remove-duplicate-lines-perl-sed-awk.html

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by M. Nejat Aydin but to make things simpler just add grep:

```
grep -q apple file.txt || sed -i '/true/a\apple' file.txt
```

Comment: Assume the first line is `apple` and the second line is `true`. That code won't append the `apple` after the `true`.

Comment: Sure, but in simple case it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e ':a;/true/!b;$a apple' -e 'n;/apple/b;i apple' -e 'ba' file
```

If a line does not contain `true` just print it.

Otherwise, if it is the last line, append the line `apple`.

Otherwise, print that line and fetch the next.

If that line contains `apple` just print it.

Otherwise, insert a line `apple` and jump to the first sed instruction since the fetched line might be one containing `true`.

N.B. This uses both the `a` command (for end of file condition) and the `i` command for when there is a following line.